# 2D Array Gradient Generation in Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, matrix, gradient

I'm still fairly green to programming and I'm trying to write a function that generates a 2D array of custom size[x,y] and will fill it with values between 0 and 1 gradually, creating something of a square/rectangular gradient.
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWHrv.png

For example:

```
[1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.6][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0]
```

I've been trying to do it for a 16x9 array for now, but it has to be usable for 100x100+ arrays.
Spent quite some time on it, but to no success, so I hope someone can help.
The closest i got was

```
[1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][0.8][1.0]
[1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0][1.0]
```

And after that a lot of weird combinations.

Comment: Can you share your code as well? Also, what exactly are the rules? Or is the value just defined in the outer 'pixel-ring' being 1.0 and then going down for each inner ring? Because that doesn't quite match the linked image...

Comment: @RolandDeschain
My code was just a double loop full of overcomplicated stupidity, but yeah, basically I was trying to make each "ring" have a lower value. On a bigger scale, the values wouldn't be much different, so when converted to colours between white(1) and black(0) the result will be a gradient like the one in the picture, without the darker lines at 45deg angles from the middle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code inside the double loop should look something like

```
var xValue = Math.Abs(x * 2f - xSize) / xSize
var yValue = Math.Abs(y * 2f - ySize) / ySize
var value = Math.Max(xValue, yValue);
```

I.e. we compute the normalized distance to the center, going from 1 at the edge, to zero at the center. Do the same thing for both x and y-coordinates, and take the maximum. Note that this code is not optimized, you can probably move some of the computations outside the loop if this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what I was looking for.